# How to dispatch an action from a promise in redux?

Tags: javascript, promise, redux

I need to dispatch an action from a promise in redux when it is resolved.
I tried with the following code (commented out) with no success.

Could you please point me out in the right direction?

Error I get is:

> ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined

```js
const getLocations = (query:string):ActionType => {
  const value = query.trim()

  if (!value.length) {
    return ({
      type: null,
      payload: null
    })
  }

  return ({
    type: types.GET_LOCATIONS,
    payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(api.find(query)).then(response => {
        resolve(response.json())
        // dispatch(myAction())
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Checkout the docs page on async actions [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) and also look into [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) and my preference [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) for async data flow in redux.

Answer (score -1):

You need middleware to catch the promise, try redux

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise

```
//index.js 
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxPromise from 'reduxPromise';

const store = createStore(reducers,  applyMiddleware(reduxPromise)));

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
, rootEl );
```

then in your action return the promise

```
return ({
   type: GET_LOCATIONS,
   payload: fetch(api.find(query))
})
```

you can google search the rest, I wrote this quickly. I do my then reaction to the response in my reducer